# Validation in Entity Framework without exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, validation, domain-driven-design

I am using Entity Framework and I want to validate my Models.

Example service:

```
var user = _userRepository.GetUser(...);
var order = user.MakeOrder();             //<- this is some business logic in Rich Domain Model
_userRepository.Update(user);
_orderRepository.Add(order);
```

Database operations may throw `DbEntityValidationException`. I can catch it and do some work to present errors to user:

```
try
{
    _userRepository.Update(user);
    _orderRepository.Add(order);
}
catch(DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
   var error = ex.EntityValidationErrors();
   //Pass errors to Controller
}
```

But I know, that **exceptions are slow**. Is there any way to do same stuff without exceptions (e.g. some kind of return values) to get better perfomance?

Comment: Do your html files are `cshtml` ?

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee, yes

Comment: Well, you want to avoid exceptions so if your getting errors on say, missing required fields, then make sure those are caught client side.

Comment: Are there any reason that you are not using the build in model validation?

Comment: Remember to accept an answer

Answer (score 2):

1) You have to implement your model IValidatableObject interface then define validation rules in Validate method

[image: Your Model]

2-) Use ModelState.IsValid property. No need try catch block

[image: Your Api]

3-) Add validation message blocks for page elements

[image: ClientSideValitaion]

For more details

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3

Additional

You can use fluent validation
https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc

Basic example http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-fluent-validation-with-asp-net-mvc-part-1-the-basics

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same method that is used internally by `DbContext.SaveChanges`. It's public - [`DbContext.GetValidationErrors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.getvalidationerrors(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Validates tracked entities and returns a Collection of DbEntityValidationResult containing validation results.

Of course you should somehow expose it by your repository.

**P.S.** But note that in fact this may lead to worse performance since `SaveChanges` will do that again (and note that this method includes `DetectChanges` call as mentioned in the remarks), so since validation errors should be an exceptional case, probably it's better to handle them as exceptional case, i.e as it is in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add validation to the model and also try to add client side validation, if you want to avoid round trip of your page. Use JQuery validation for client side validation for better performance.

For more details on client side validation. Try to go through below link :

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation
2. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the build in model validation before trying to save to your database.

This example is from the login feature in the build in asp.net mvc template.

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

And in the view:

```
@using WebApplication1.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                    </p>*@
            }
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="socialLoginForm">
            @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Html helper method, ValidationMessageFor will use the text in the display annotation to inform what's wrong.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13653732)

Comment: I know. I was on my phone on my way to bed. I'll be editing the answer later today during a break at work.